# How do I give a text key to a dataframe stored as a value in a dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops, dictionary, dataframe

So I have 3 dataframes - df1,df2.df3. I'm trying to loop through each dataframe so that I can run some preprocessing - set date time, extract hour to a separate column etc. However, I'm running into some issues:

If I store the df in a dict as in `df_dict = {'df1' : df1, 'df2' : df2, 'df3' : df3}` and then loop through it as in

```
for k, v in df_dict.items():
    if k == 'df1':
        v['Col1']....
    else:
        v['Coln']....
```

I get a `NameError: name 'df1' is not defined`

What am I doing wrong? I initially thought I was not reading in the df1..3 data in but that seems to operate ok (as in it doesn't fail and its clearly reading it in given the time lag (they are big files)). The code preceding it (for load) is:

```
DF_DATA = { 'df1': 'df1.csv','df2': 'df2.csv', 'df3': 'df3.csv' }
for k,v in DF_DATA.items():
    print(k, v) #this works to print out both key and value
    k = pd.read_csv(v) #this does not
```

I am thinking this maybe the cause but not sure.I'm expecting the load loop to create the 3 dataframes and put them into memory. Then for the loop on the top of the page, I want to reference the string key in my if block condition so that each df can get a slightly different preprocessing treatment.

Thanks very much in advance for your assist.

Comment: Can you show how your dataframes look, because I tried out your approach and it worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't create `df_dict` correctly. Try this:

```
DF_DATA = { 'df1': 'df1.csv','df2': 'df2.csv', 'df3': 'df3.csv' }
df_dict= {k:pd.read_csv(v) for k,v in DF_DATA.items()}
```

Comment: That didn't work. So I entered: `DF_DATA = { 'df1': 'df1.csv', 'df2': 'df2.csv', 'df3': 'df3.csv' }
df_dict= {k:pd.read_csv(v) for k,v in DF_DATA.items()}` but got `NameError: name 'df1' is not defined` when I tried `df1.info()` after executing the load.

Comment: @sandeepmohan If you are following the code above, we didn’t create df1 object.

Comment: D'ohh. Good point. Guess the sleep did me good. I see it now. That's brilliant. One last thing - how would I break it out of the dict so that I don't need to iterate through all 3 dframes when I want to operate only on one. Or do you recommend that I leave it in the dict when I want to do a groupby just on df2. I was able to do the pre processing super fast with your method but later on in the code I need to reference just one of the df rather than all.

Comment: @sandeepmohan Assume that you want to get the dataframe of "df2.csv". Then you can select it from `df_dict` by the string `'df2'`. In other words, `dict_df['df2']`.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help, Ken. This gets it done!! Also for simplicity sake - for groupby and other function calls, I just assigned each df reference to a variable. Easier to key in ... `Df1 = dict_df['df2']` .